Unable to use IF statement in plpgsql
Here is the relevant part of my code (Please note, ignoredwp is a boolean function parameter):
where 
 
cp.imei in (select distinct IMEI from imei_clustered) 

and cp."generatedAt"::date between cs."campaignStartDate" and cs."campaignEndDate"


    IF ignoredwp=true THEN
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM filtering f 
            WHERE f."IMEI" = cp.imei 
              AND f.date = cp."generatedAt"::date
        );
    END if;    

This throws an error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "IF"

I don't know this language, but I guess the syntax is something like .... and if .. then ... else true end if, not ... if ... then and ... endif. (You might even be able to remove the if and use boolean operators instead)

I tried "and
IF ignoredwp=true THEN
       NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM filtering f 
        WHERE f."IMEI" = cp.imei 
          AND f.date = cp."generatedAt"::date
    );
END if; "-------- but this gave ERROR: syntax error at or near "ignoredwp"


IF is a PL/pgSQL command. You cannot use PL/pgSQL commands in the middle of SQL statements. Normally, the solution is to use a SQL CASE expression instead, but since you are trying to compose an SQL statement, you'll have to use dynamic SQL:
DECLARE
   sql text;
BEGIN
   sql := $sql$SELECT ... WHERE ...$sql$;

   IF ignoredwp THEN
      sql := sql || $sql$ AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM filtering f 
            WHERE f."IMEI" = cp.imei 
              AND f.date = cp."generatedAt"::date
        )$sql$;
   END IF;

   EXECUTE sql;
END;

If you need to process the results from the query, use EXECUTE sql INTO var or loop with FOR var IN EXECUTE sql LOOP.
